# How can I change graphical settings without launching the game?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I am encountering a persistent DirectX error that began after beating the boss of the prologue, and has since prevented me from from even launching the game. The most likely cause that I can figure after some Googling is that I set one or more graphical settings beyond the capabilities of my system.

[image: DirectX Error]

However I am having difficulty troubleshooting this point, as I cannot figure out how to alter the game's graphical settings from outside the game. I cannot even reach the menu screen without the above error crashing the game before it loads to that point.

So is there any way to alter the graphics settings from outside the game, or is my only option to reinstall the entire thing from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of poking around, we managed to find the configuration information.  For Windows 7, the file is `\Documents\BioWare\Dragon Age Inquisition\Save\ProfileOptions_profile`.

The options are a bit dense, but opening this file in Notepad allows you to make modifications without the game running.

Comment: Alternatively, you could probably rename that file and let the launcher recreate it (they usually do that, though I have not tested it with DA:I). That would revert it to defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with Windows 10 and renaming the file to "rename" launched the game with the default settings, although trying to open the file via notepad proved to be inconclusive.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/197105), isn't it?